# Hibernate JOIN FETCH with reference to the same table by different properties results in 1+N queries?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'll try to include all the relevant bits of information without overloading with too much.  I have this object (stripped of a lot of irrelevant stuff):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RoutingAliases")
public class RoutingAlias {
    private Queue queue;
    private Queue scheduleQueue;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "queue_id", referencedColumnName = "other_id")
    public Queue getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "schedule_queue_id", referencedColumnName = "other_id")
    public Queue getScheduleQueue() {
        return scheduleQueue;
    }
}
```

Note that `"queue"` and "`scheduleQueue"` refer to the same object type/table via different properties.  Either or both could be `NULL` or not.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Queues")
public class Queue { 
    private Long id;
    private Long queue
    private Long otherId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "queue_id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "queue")
    public String getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "other_id")
    public Long getOtherId() {
        return otherId;
    }
}
```

I try to retrieve a list of all `RoutingAliases` from my DAO class:

```
return em.createQuery("SELECT ra FROM RoutingAlias AS ra " +
"LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH ra.queue AS q " +
"LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH ra.scheduleQueue AS sq ", 
RoutingAlias.class).getResultList();
```

The SQL that gets generated results in a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between `RoutingAliases` and `Queue` tables with two references to `Queue`s under different table aliases.  In other words, the initial query returns all the details necessary to populate `RoutingAlias.queue` and `RoutingAlias.scheduleQueue` with a single query.  But what happens is, after all the `RoutingAliases` are retrieved (there are about 1150 in the database), Hibernate then makes an additional 1150 queries to the `Queues` table - the 1+N query problem.  The generated SQL is valid, and I can copy-paste into a SQL window and it works fine.  I've stripped out every extra bit of code from the actual code until all I've left is the above properties and the above HQL/JPQL statement.  If I remove the reference to one of the `Queue` properties (either of them), it results in a single query.  If I put the second one back in, it goes back to 1+N queries.  If I remove the "`JOIN FETCH`" from the query and put a `@Fetch` on the properties instead, it does 1+(N*2) queries. Frankly, I'm stumped, as this is such a simple case that I'm out of things to try.

The only odd thing about the situation is that the `FK` between `RoutingAlias` and `Queue` is NOT via the primary key on the `Queue` table, but another property in the `Queues` table, which shouldn't make any difference since, as mentioned, pulling a list of Routing Aliases with just one Queue relationship works just fine in a single query.

EDIT: If I retrieve a single instance of `RoutingAlias`, (using the `find()` method to retrieve by `ID`) the system will retrieve it, and associated objects, in a single SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in Hibernate - I can reproduce this issue as well.

However it **works fine** if I change the type of `scheduleQueue` from `Queue` to Queue2 and create a copy of the entity `Queue` named `Queue2` (leaving it mapped to the same table !)

You can extract a superclass from these two classes

I have struggled a lot with such issues and wrote a small library for checking the number of queries generated by Hibernate - you might find it useful: https://github.com/bedrin/jdbc-sniffer